# How to make this shape in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, uibezierpath

I want to create this badge or direction-type view in swift. I cannot use image because text can be long in other languages. I want to make it with UIView. I want to achieve this:

[image]

I managed to make it with sharp points with this code

```
class ArrowView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // Starting point: Top left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - self.frame.height/2, y: 0)) // Move to the top right before the arrow point
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height/2)) // Move to the tip of the arrow
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - self.frame.height/2, y: self.frame.height)) // Move to the bottom right before the arrow point
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height)) // Move to the bottom left
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor // Choose the color of the arrow

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        self.commonInit()
    }
}
```

How to make line joint rounded like the actual design?

Comment: So show us how you tried using a BezierPath.

Comment: Are you looking for `shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round`?

Comment: shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round is not working for me.

Comment: @AnkitSingh - The image you posted that you "want to achieve" is very small, and it looks like what your code is producing. ***Explain what you want*** that is different (and/or post a larger image so we can see the difference). For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC44O.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DonMag I need 3rd one. The blue view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option...

Work with `CGMutablePath` and take advantage of tangent curves:

```
@IBDesignable
class ArrowView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 6.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAShapeLayer.self }
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { layer as! CAShapeLayer }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // may want to include this to make sure self's background is clear
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        // set the shape fill color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor

        // use rect as reference to bounds
        //  makes it easy if we want to inset the shape
        let rect: CGRect = bounds
        
        let arrowInset: CGFloat = rect.height / 2.0 //- cornerRadius / 2.0
        
        // top-left corner
        let pt1: CGPoint = .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
        // top-right curve
        let pt2: CGPoint = .init(x: rect.maxX - arrowInset, y: rect.minY)
        // arrow point
        let pt3: CGPoint = .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY)
        // bottom-right curve
        let pt4: CGPoint = .init(x: rect.maxX - arrowInset, y: rect.maxY)
        // bottom-left corner
        let pt5: CGPoint = .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
        
        let cPath: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
        
        cPath.move(to: pt1)
        cPath.addArc(tangent1End: pt2, tangent2End: pt3, radius: cornerRadius)
        cPath.addArc(tangent1End: pt3, tangent2End: pt4, radius: cornerRadius)
        cPath.addArc(tangent1End: pt4, tangent2End: pt5, radius: cornerRadius)
        cPath.addLine(to: pt5)
        cPath.closeSubpath()
        
        shapeLayer.path = cPath
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Note: I used the same `@IBInspectable` properties to make it easy for you to compare with Rob's implementation.

Answer (score 4):

A few observations:

- One way to do this is to stroke the outline of the curved arrow; that entails drawing lines for the straight edges and arcs for the corners, requiring in 10 strokes (i.e., five edges and five corners);
- Another (simpler) way to do it is with a path that consists of just five straight edges, but round the corners of the joins. The trick is, given a desired “corner radius”, to:

  - inset the path by the amount of the corner radius,
  - stroke the path with a `lineWidth` of twice the corner radius, and
  - use a `lineJoin` of `.round`.

  That requires only 5 strokes. To help visualize what is going on, here it is using a different color for the stroke than the fill:

  [image]

  Or if you set the stroke to be the same color, you get the shape you intended:

  [image]

  And you can achieve that with:

  ```swift
  @IBDesignable
  class ArrowView: UIView {
      override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAShapeLayer.self }
      var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { layer as! CAShapeLayer }

      @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 6 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
      @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

      override func layoutSubviews() {
          super.layoutSubviews()

          let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: cornerRadius, dy: cornerRadius)
          let arrowInset = rect.height / 2

          let path = UIBezierPath()
          path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
          path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - arrowInset, y: rect.minY))
          path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
          path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - arrowInset, y: rect.maxY))
          path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
          path.close()

          shapeLayer.lineWidth = cornerRadius * 2
          shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
          shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
          shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
          shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
      }
  }
  ```

---

A few additional observations:

1. I have made that `@IBDesignable` (so I can add it in IB and set the color and radius on the property sheet), but that is optional.
2. Note, you want to use [`bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds), not [`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame) in this path routine. The former is in the coordinate system of the current view, but the latter is the coordinate system of its `superview` (which is not what you want).
3. I am setting the base [`layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass) to be a `CAShapeLayer`, which saves me from having to add another layer in the view. That is, again, optional, but simplifies the code a little.
4. In [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews/), make sure to call `super` rendition.

---

If you do not want the left edges rounded, too, the easiest way is to (a) not close the path; and (b) do not inset from left:

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let rect = bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: cornerRadius, left: 0, bottom: cornerRadius, right: cornerRadius))
    let arrowInset = rect.height / 2

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - arrowInset, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - arrowInset, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    // path.close()

    shapeLayer.lineWidth = cornerRadius * 2
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
}
```

Yielding (with black stroke):

[image]

Or with same colored stroke:

[image]

Comment: I played a bit with this code and added the capability to point left, right, up and down. maybe someone finds it useful: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2570289

Comment: @Rob Thanks, This is exactly what I am looking for. Can you please tell me how to prevent the left side corners to be round?

Comment: Don't close the path. See revised answer.

Comment: But I think you should accept DonMag’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76706178/1271826), rather than this kludgy approach.